# How to restrict number of successful frontend logins per user

Tags: login, front-end

Is there any plugin for restrict number of successful frontend logins per user? I looked around but without success, and have no idea how to achieve that on the other way. Any advice? Joomla is 3.8.1

Comment: Please confirm that my understand is correct with what you want: - You want 1 user could only log in your front end for example 20 times, after that, that user could not log in any more?

Comment: Yes, Ron, exactly that. In ideal case that number of logins per user is not constant, ie. it could be defined for every user separately.

Answer (score 1):

if *"restrict number of successful frontend logins per user"* is one per user, then **Login One!** might be what you want.

If you need more logins >1 then you 'll probably need the Business edition

https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/login-one/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, there should be 10-20 logins.

Comment: They have a Login One! Business edition that they say that "The maximum number of simultaneuous log-ins for 'allowed users' can be configured;" https://www.innato.nl/offering/software-development/repository/Innato-bv---Software-Vault/Joomla-3.x/20---Plugins/10---Login-One-Plug-in---J3/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=17&virtuemart_category_id=1&Itemid=129

Comment: Thank you again, but as I understand this plugin restrict maximum number of simultaneous logins. Maybe my question is not clear enough - I search for a way to restrict total number of logins, not just simultaneous ones.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin Login Limiter will do the job.
https://www.innato.nl/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=17&catid=11&Itemid=121#plugin_login_limiter_j30

Comment: @Vladimir Kraguljac have you tried my suggestion? If so, was it successful? If so, can you mark it as the accepted answer please?